How to bends in a pipe influence the heat transfer rate?
We can calculate the energy required to heat water flowing through a pipe using the formula
˙=˙Δ
Where
 is the heat transfer rate (in watts, W),  is the mass flow rate (in kilograms per second, kg/s),  is the specific heat capacity (in joules per kilogram per degree Celsius, J/(kg·°C)), and Δ is the change in temperature (in degrees Celsius, °C).
I am interested to know how bends in the pipe would influence the values in this formula. Do bends in the pipe change the mass flow rate value?
I have read on this website  that "Headloss (also sometimes referred to as friction or pressure loss) is a measure of the amount the flow rate will be slowed down by a combination of friction with the pipe wall and turbulence as the fluid passes through fittings." Does this mean that a pipe with bends will experience a lower mass flow rate, which decreases the heat transfer rate?
I have also heard that a turbulent flow heats faster than a laminar flow - if the bends in the pipe increase the turbulence, which value in the formula would change?

For a fixed liquid flow rate, the pressure drop in The tube increases a little on the heat transfer is enhanced a little.
